# Using folium maps in flask

Tags: python, flask, maps, folium

I am fairly new to Flask and developing in general. I am trying to create a basic map using folium with a flask application. I believe the issue involves my routes.py file as I am able to get a map to display using Jupyter Notebooks. Below is my code:

```
mapcompanies.py:  
`import folium   
import pandas as pd    


def createMap():
    df = pd.read_csv("./app/static/media/corporations.csv")

    mapthis= folium.Map(location=[42.456, -71.345], zoom_start=6, tiles='Mapbox bright')

    #mapthis.save(outfile='./map.html')
    return mapthis`
```

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: routes.py: `import os
import json .   
import pandas as pd .  
from app import app .  
from flask import render_template, Markup, send_file  
from app.forms import currencyForm, InputGDP .  
from werkzeug.urls import url_parse .  
from app.convert import convertThis, CalculateGDP .  
from app.mapcompanies import createMap .                                      @app.route('/show_map') .    
def show_map():    
    createMap() .  
    return render_template('map.html',  
 createMap=createMap()) .  




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)`

Comment: i am also using jinja templates in an html file called map.html: `<iframe>{{url_for('show_map')}}</iframe>`. My page returns a blank iframe box with no content in it.

Comment: Please don't add such a lot of code in a comment. It is unreadable. Instead, edit your question and put it there.